# python-click: dependent options on another option

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

This question is about the [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) package: I want to setup my command so that  some `optional options` are dependent on a specific option value and are required based on its value.

**Required options:**

1. input (input file)
2. doe (integer , represents algo name)

**Sub options:**
if doe is

1. equal to `1` then **option** `generator_string` should become `required=True`
2. equal to `2` then **option** `number_of_sample_points`should become `required=True`
3. equal to `3` then **option** `number_of_center_points`should become `required=True`

**Valid Examples:**

1. `--input ./input.txt --doe 1 --generator_string 1234`
2. `--input ./input.txt --doe 2 --number_of_sample_points 3`
3. `--input ./input.txt --doe 3 --number_of_center_points 2`

**CODE:**

```py
import click


def check_output(ctx, param, value):
    if value == 1:
        if not ctx.params['generator_string']:
            setOptionAsRequired(ctx, 'generator_string')
    return value


def setOptionAsRequired(ctx, name):
    for p in ctx.command.params:
        if isinstance(p, click.Option) and p.name == name:
            p.required = True


@click.option('--input', required=True, type=click.Path(exists=True) )
@click.option('--doe', required=True, type=int, callback=check_output )
@click.option('--generator_string', required=False, type=str, is_eager=True)
@click.option('--number_of_sample_points', required=False, type=int, is_eager=True)
@click.option('--number_of_center_points', required=False, type=int, is_eager=True)
@click.command(context_settings=dict(max_content_width=800))
def main(input, doe, generator_string, number_of_sample_points, number_of_center_points):
    click.echo('is valid command')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can make the 3 possible values of `--doe` as [subcommands](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#commands-and-groups). Each subcommand can have completely different options.

Comment: Yes but i dont have commands like sync , i just have options or arguments , see my examples , also algos have very long name that`s why i am using numbers. any ideas ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest doing that with a custom `click.Command` class like:

#### Custom Class:

```
def command_required_option_from_option(require_name, require_map):

    class CommandOptionRequiredClass(click.Command):

        def invoke(self, ctx):
            require = ctx.params[require_name]
            if require not in require_map:
                raise click.ClickException(
                    "Unexpected value for --'{}': {}".format(
                        require_name, require))
            if ctx.params[require_map[require].lower()] is None:
                raise click.ClickException(
                    "With {}={} must specify option --{}".format(
                        require_name, require, require_map[require]))
            super(CommandOptionRequiredClass, self).invoke(ctx)

    return CommandOptionRequiredClass
```

#### Using the Custom Class

```
required_options = {
    1: 'generator_string',
    2: 'number_of_sample_points',
    3: 'number_of_center_points',
}

@click.command(cls=command_required_option_from_option('doe', required_options))
...
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.command()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Command` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Command` in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case, we override `click.Command.invoke()` and then validate that the required option has been set before running the command

#### Test Code:

```
import click

required_options = {
    1: 'generator_string',
    2: 'number_of_sample_points',
    3: 'number_of_center_points',
}

@click.command(context_settings=dict(max_content_width=800),
               cls=command_required_option_from_option('doe', required_options))
@click.option('--input', required=True,
              type=click.Path(exists=True))
@click.option('--doe', required=True, type=int)
@click.option('--generator_string', required=False, type=str, is_eager=True)
@click.option('--number_of_sample_points', required=False, type=int,
              is_eager=True)
@click.option('--number_of_center_points', required=False, type=int,
              is_eager=True)
def main(input, doe, generator_string, number_of_sample_points,
         number_of_center_points):
    click.echo('input: {}'.format(input))
    click.echo('doe: {}'.format(doe))
    click.echo('generator_string: {}'.format(generator_string))
    click.echo('Num of sample_points: {}'.format(number_of_sample_points))
    click.echo('Num of center_points: {}'.format(number_of_center_points))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '--input ./input.txt --doe 0',
        '--input ./input.txt --doe 1',
        '--input ./input.txt --doe 2',
        '--input ./input.txt --doe 3',
        '--input ./input.txt --doe 1 --generator_string 1234',
        '--input ./input.txt --doe 2 --number_of_sample_points 3',
        '--input ./input.txt --doe 3 --number_of_center_points 2',
        '',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            main(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> --input ./input.txt --doe 0
Error: Unexpected value for --'doe': 0
-----------
> --input ./input.txt --doe 1
Error: With doe=1 must specify option --generator_string
-----------
> --input ./input.txt --doe 2
Error: With doe=2 must specify option --number_of_sample_points
-----------
> --input ./input.txt --doe 3
Error: With doe=3 must specify option --number_of_center_points
-----------
> --input ./input.txt --doe 1 --generator_string 1234
input: ./input.txt
doe: 1
generator_string: 1234
Num of sample_points: None
Num of center_points: None
-----------
> --input ./input.txt --doe 2 --number_of_sample_points 3
input: ./input.txt
doe: 2
generator_string: None
Num of sample_points: 3
Num of center_points: None
-----------
> --input ./input.txt --doe 3 --number_of_center_points 2
input: ./input.txt
doe: 3
generator_string: None
Num of sample_points: None
Num of center_points: 2
-----------
> 
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Error: Missing option "--input".
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --input PATH                    [required]
  --doe INTEGER                   [required]
  --generator_string TEXT
  --number_of_sample_points INTEGER
  --number_of_center_points INTEGER
  --help                          Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: Not relevant question but click does not support camelCase ? |
If i write ```@click.option('--generatorString')``` it does not work

Comment: also I think i dont need ```, is_eager=True``` for sub required options .. right ??

Comment: Click normalizes the names. I made a minor edit to allow camel case.  You will still need to have `main()` take a flattened case, but to the user it will be camelCase.

Comment: asked a formatting question here , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585564/python-click-formatting-help-text

Comment: is it possible to do the same with prompts?