# Set Choices for a click option based on another option

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I want an option in click to have different choices based on the value of another option. Basically I want something like this:

```
@click.option(
    "--model",
    "model_name",
    if model_ver ==1:
        type=click.Choice(['model_1.0", "model_1.1", "model_1.2']),
    if model_ver ==2:
        type=click.Choice(['model_2.0', 'model_2.1', 'model_2.2'])
```

The above obviously does not work. Is it possible to get click to do what I am trying?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584012/python-click-dependent-options-on-another-option